# stock price at 4:00am when the pre-market opens

Tags: stocks

What happens to the stock price when pre-market opens at 4:00am? Will there be a significant different to the close price at 8:00pm on the previous day? I have never got up so early to watch the stock price at 4:00am.

Comment: There _can_ be. _Will_ there be a significant difference? Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Most stocks do not trade as early as 4:00 am unless there is specific news in the stock and/or national or global economic or political news that affects them.

Story stocks like TSLA and the FAANG stocks may trade modestly circa 4:00 am in the absence of such news but price will not differ much from the previous 8:00 pm close unless there is a reason for it to change (news).